# calculating the LM test statistic and P value

Tags: econometrics, regression

[image]

Include the LM test,

Questions:  1. What regression would be needed to test the null hypothesis of no autocorrelation in
the residuals against the alternative of order 1 autocorrelation by the Breusch-Godfrey
(BG) test?
2. What do you conclude from this test at the 5% significance level? Explain.